Writing not allowed due to timeout or cancellation
When I run my app it gives me this error after successful compilation and gradle buil Error running 'app' Writing not allowed due to timeout or cancellation
When I run same app on different devices. It doesn't give me any error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What worked for me was a combination of the other answers and an IDE restart:

Uninstalled app from the device

Restarted ADB using command: adb kill-server; adb start-server

Removed USB cable and replugged it (Still didn't work at this point)

Restarted Android Studio
(Now able to launch my app on the device!)



Just wanted to share that the issue happened again today. I simply restarted Android Studio, and after that, my app launched as expected on the device.
("File" menu -> "Invalidate Caches..." -> "Just restart")

It happened to make when I had a faulty Live edit attempt. To resolve it I did the following steps:

Uninstall the currently installed app from the device (adb uninstall $package$)
Restart adb (adb kill-server; adb start-server)
Run the app


I just removed the USB cable and replugged it, it got working. Seems like a Live Edit Problem
